# Functional implementation of collecting objects into groups

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to write more functional Javascript with the underscore library. Any thoughts on how to improve this to be more functional than imperative? Also, any way to do this without `mapObject`?

The first of each pair is a "bucket" and the second is a value, I'd like to iterate over the information and get a unique list of what is in each bucket.

```
var a = [
  ['A',1],
  ['A',1],
  ['A',1],
  ['A',2],
  ['B',1],
  ['B',2],
  ['B',2],
  ['B',4],
  ['C',6],
  ['D',5]
];

//result should be:
//  {
//     A: [1,2],
//     B: [1,2,4],
//     C: [6],
//     D: [5]
//  }

_.chain(a)
 .groupBy(function (pair) {
    var group = pair[0];
    return group;
 })
 .mapObject(function (val, key) {
    var results = _.chain(val)
                   .map(function (pair) {
                     return pair[1]
                   })
                   .uniq()
                   .value();
    return results;
 })
 .value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can avoid a few variable assignments by returning immediately,
also by using some details of the Underscore.js API, that is by
specifying the used indexes for `groupBy`/`map` directly.

```
_.chain(a)
 .groupBy(0)
 .mapObject(function (val, key) {
    return _.chain(val).map(1).uniq().value();
 })
 .value();
```

I doubt there's a good way to avoid `mapObject`, after all, that's what
it's for.

With 1.7 you could also write that even less verbose:

```
_.chain(a)
 .groupBy(0)
 .mapObject((val, key) => _.chain(val).map(1).uniq().value())
 .value();
```

Looks pretty functional to me.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm forced to use an older version of underscore that didn't have `mapObject ` but I worked around it by chaining `map` and then `object`.